# Can I derive a grandchild for a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I want to know, whether C# supports grandchild classes or not. I want to do the next:

```
class Base
{
}

class DerivedFromBase : Base
{
}

class Grandchild : DerivedFromBase //I recieve an error in this class
{
}
```

In Java I might to do so, but C# generates an error in Grandchild class. Does It support only one derived class?

Comment: What compiler error you get ?

Comment: Error is "class 'Grandchild' exceeds level of derivation".

Comment: I have never heard of that error. What's the error number?

Comment: What compiler are you using? That error doesn't appear on google for C#.

Comment: This code compiles fine. You need to provider other details like which compiler are you using etc

Comment: Do different compilers act differently?

Comment: Yes, now tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to learn, but also a place to teach. People have asked you to mention the compiler you are using. They asked not only so they could help you more easily, but also because they might learn something from your question. So please be so kind and state what compiler you did use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# allows this so there should be no error.

I reproduced what you have shown us, with some added code, and it works. So it must be something else that causes the error.

Check here, this works:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
      Grandchild g = new Grandchild();
  }
}

class Base
{
    public int i=10;
}

class DerivedFromBase : Base
{
    public DerivedFromBase()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

class Grandchild : DerivedFromBase 
{
   public Grandchild()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, please post your error. Also note your base is already derived from `Object`, so `DerivedFromBase` is a grandchild.

Answer (score 0):

C# supports (practically) unlimited levels of derivation. If you're getting an error, it's caused by something else.

Answer (score 0):

It supports just one derived class, but that class can be a derived class as well. Just as in Java. Your problem is elsewhere.

Prepare a question with minimal code that reproduces your situation, and post it alongside the compiler output.

Comment: What do you mean by "supports just one derived class"?